# Date Difference between timestamp excluding weekends and range time (out of business hours) Pyspark

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark, datediff, weekday

I have, for each ID, a "start_date" timestamp column and I would like to calculate the exact difference with an "end_date" date but with a particularity: I would like count all hours only between 9AM-6PM and only during working days (not weekends).

For example:

INPUT:

| ID | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **2022-02-10T14:00:00.323Z** | **2022-02-14T21:00:00.323Z** |
| 2 | **2022-02-09T17:00:00.323Z** | **2022-02-15T13:00:00.323Z** |
| 3 | **2022-02-01T08:00:00.323Z** | **2022-02-01T12:00:00.323Z** |

OUTPUT:

| ID | START_DATE | END_DATE | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **2022-02-10T14:00:00.323Z** | **2022-02-14T21:00:00.323Z** | **22(4h[10]+9h[11]+9h[14])** |
| 2 | **2022-02-09T17:00:00.323Z** | **2022-02-15T13:00:00.323Z** | **32(1h[09]+9h[day 10]+9h[day 11]+9h[day 14]+4h[day 15])** |
| 3 | **2022-02-01T08:00:00.323Z** | **2022-02-01T12:00:00.323Z** | **4** |

Thank u for your support!

Answer (score 1):

We need to do several steps for that.

## 1. Create the test set

```py
from datetime import datetime


spark = Spark()

a = [
    (1, datetime(2022, 2, 10, 14), datetime(2022, 2, 14, 21)),
    (2, datetime(2022, 2, 9, 17), datetime(2022, 2, 15, 13)),
    (3, datetime(2022, 2, 1, 8), datetime(2022, 2, 1, 12)),
]

b = "ID START_DATE  END_DATE".split()

df = spark.createDataFrame(a, b)

df.show()
+---+-------------------+-------------------+                                   
| ID|         START_DATE|           END_DATE|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1|2022-02-10 14:00:00|2022-02-14 21:00:00|
|  2|2022-02-09 17:00:00|2022-02-15 13:00:00|
|  3|2022-02-01 08:00:00|2022-02-01 12:00:00|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
```

## 2. Compute the in-between dates

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn(
    "day",
    F.explode(F.sequence(F.lit(0), F.datediff(F.col("end_date"), F.col("start_date")))),
)

df = df.select(
    "id",
    F.greatest(
        F.col("start_date"),
        F.expr("date_add(start_date, day)"),
    ).alias("start_date"),
    F.least(
        F.col("end_date"),
        F.expr("date_add(start_date, day+1)"),
    ).alias("end_date"),
)

df.show()
+---+-------------------+-------------------+                                   
| id|         start_date|           end_date|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1|2022-02-10 14:00:00|2022-02-11 00:00:00|
|  1|2022-02-11 00:00:00|2022-02-12 00:00:00|
|  1|2022-02-12 00:00:00|2022-02-13 00:00:00|
|  1|2022-02-13 00:00:00|2022-02-14 00:00:00|
|  1|2022-02-14 00:00:00|2022-02-14 21:00:00|
|  2|2022-02-09 17:00:00|2022-02-10 00:00:00|
|  2|2022-02-10 00:00:00|2022-02-11 00:00:00|
|  2|2022-02-11 00:00:00|2022-02-12 00:00:00|
|  2|2022-02-12 00:00:00|2022-02-13 00:00:00|
|  2|2022-02-13 00:00:00|2022-02-14 00:00:00|
|  2|2022-02-14 00:00:00|2022-02-15 00:00:00|
|  2|2022-02-15 00:00:00|2022-02-15 13:00:00|
|  3|2022-02-01 08:00:00|2022-02-01 12:00:00|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
```

## 3. Remove useless data (weekend and extra-hours)

```py
# Remove weekends
df = df.where(~F.date_format(F.col("start_date"), "u").isin("6", "7"))

# Reduce timeframe to 9AM-->6PM
df = df.withColumn(
    "start_date",
    F.greatest(
        F.col("start_date"),
        F.col("start_date").cast("date").cast("timestamp") + F.expr("INTERVAL 9 HOURS"),
    ),
).withColumn(
    "end_date",
    F.least(
        F.col("end_date"),
        F.col("start_date").cast("date").cast("timestamp") + F.expr("INTERVAL 18 HOURS"),
    ),
)

df.show()
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
| id|         start_date|           end_date|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1|2022-02-10 14:00:00|2022-02-10 18:00:00|
|  1|2022-02-11 09:00:00|2022-02-11 18:00:00|
|  1|2022-02-14 09:00:00|2022-02-14 18:00:00|
|  2|2022-02-09 17:00:00|2022-02-09 18:00:00|
|  2|2022-02-10 09:00:00|2022-02-10 18:00:00|
|  2|2022-02-11 09:00:00|2022-02-11 18:00:00|
|  2|2022-02-14 09:00:00|2022-02-14 18:00:00|
|  2|2022-02-15 09:00:00|2022-02-15 13:00:00|
|  3|2022-02-01 09:00:00|2022-02-01 12:00:00|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
```

## 4. Compute and aggregate

```py
df = df.groupBy("id").agg(
    F.sum((F.unix_timestamp("end_date") - F.unix_timestamp("start_date")) / 3600).alias(
        "time"
    )
)

df.show()
+---+----+
| id|time|
+---+----+
|  1|22.0|
|  3| 3.0|
|  2|32.0|
+---+----+
```

Comment: Thank u Steven! I have to test this solution on my project... Thanks for now!

Comment: @Jresearcher I think you can adapt a little bit the code to keep the start and end columns. Just tell me if you need help